# correlation between two columns with respect to fixed column

Tags: python, pandas

my dataset has 3 columns (state,death_rate,avg_speed)

I want to find the correlation between the avg_speed and death_rate with respect to state

I tried this but it returned an empty dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_csv('result.csv', header=None, usecols=[1,2]) #read 
result = dataset.corr()
print result
```

and how to represent the result?

EDIT:

here is sample data

```
state    death_rate     avg_speed
AL         50          43.08966565
AK         42          12.16736296
AZ         52          43.33464079
AR         28          36.88461538
CA         30          48.74048562
CO         28          27.54417671
CT         26          23.10909091
FL         18          58.58169492
GA         86          43.55456453
HI         95          66.83672039
ID         99          30.63928113
IL         98          25.06262626
```

Comment: Paste some data here

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It seems like you only use two columns in your `usecols` argument?

Comment: @Zhiya yea those two columns that I want to find the correlation between them

Comment: Are the values in your `results.csv` file comma separated or whitespace separated (like you've shown in your sample data)? Also, if you print your `dataset` dataframe, can you see if the column headers ('death_rate', 'avg_speed') are present in the first row as strings?

Answer (score 0):

@bunji made a good point. There are actually several problems based on your sample data:

1. `header` should not be set to `None` because you do have a header;
2. You may want to set `sep` or `delimiter` appropriately based on your data. The sample data you gave does not seem to be a standard format. I tried both space and tab (`\t`) and neither worked.

You can try to print `dataset` or call `dataset.columns` to check if you have read it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few separate issues here...

The data sample you provided wont allow you to calculate the correlations for each state because you only have 1 row per state. So I slightly modified your data sample just so the following examples work. Im assuming in your actual data file you have multiple rows per state. Here is what I'm working with:

```
state    death_rate     avg_speed
AL         50          43.08966565
AL         42          12.16736296
AL         52          43.33464079
CA         28          36.88461538
CA         30          48.74048562
CA         28          27.54417671
CA         26          23.10909091
FL         18          58.58169492
FL         86          43.55456453
AL         95          66.83672039
AL         99          30.63928113
FL         98          25.06262626
```

As mentioned in some of the comments, you shouldn't be using `header=None` because your datafile does contain a header row. Additionally, you need to import all columns rather than limiting it to just 2, so you should omit `usecols=[1,2]`

It looks like your input data is white space delimited, so you need to use `delim_whitespace` to import it correctly. This will let you correctly import the data into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv("result.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
```

To calculate the correlation between `death_rate` and `avg_speed` separately for each state you need to use a `groupby` before you use `corr()`. Furthermore, `corr()` will give you a correlation matrix, but I'm guessing you just want the single correlation value for each state. We can get this by just tidying up the dataframe after calculating the correlation matrices

First we groupby `state` and calculate the correlation matrices:

```
result = df.groupby('state').corr()

                  avg_speed  death_rate
state                                  
AL    avg_speed    1.000000    0.482542
      death_rate   0.482542    1.000000
CA    avg_speed    1.000000    0.922646
      death_rate   0.922646    1.000000
FL    avg_speed    1.000000   -0.903176
      death_rate  -0.903176    1.000000
```

Then we reset the index and pull out state and one of the other columns (the other column just contains duplicate information as youre only working with 2 variables):

```
result = result.reset_index()[['state', 'avg_speed']]

  state  avg_speed
0    AL   1.000000
1    AL   0.482542
2    CA   1.000000
3    CA   0.922646
4    FL   1.000000
5    FL  -0.903176
```

Finally, remove the rows where the correlation is `1`, and optionally rename the column to something more sensible:

```
result = result[~result['avg_speed'].eq(1)].rename(columns={'avg_speed': 'corr'})
```

Which will give you:

```
  state      corr
1    AL  0.482542
3    CA  0.922646
5    FL -0.903176
```